# Monotouch WCF reference wizard crashes

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

When trying to add a reference to a ASMX with WCF I get the following ewrror. Using the .NET 2.0 services option however works fine:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Mono.ServiceContractTool.MoonlightChannelBaseOperationExtension.FixupAsync () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.ServiceContractTool.MoonlightChannelBaseOperationExtension.Fixup () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.ServiceContractTool.MoonlightChannelBaseContext.Fixup () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WCF.WebServiceDiscoveryResultWCF.CreateProxyFile (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject dotNetProject, FilePath basePath, System.String proxyNamespace, System.String referenceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WebServiceDiscoveryResult.GenerateFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject project, System.String namspace, System.String referenceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Commands.WebReferenceCommandHandler.NewWebReference () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Please file a bug against MonoDevelop and include the service you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono does not have a compatible version of SlSvcUtil.exe, so you need to use the slsvcutil that Microsoft provides as part of the Silverlight 3.0 Tools to generate the client proxy.

http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF

Comment: Worked nicely. Here's the command I use to build out the service if others need it:

slsvcutil.exe http://localhost/FreePOC/Timesheet.svc?wsdl /namespace:"*,FreePOC.Services"  /d:z:\desktop /noConfig  /ser:DataContractSerializer

This runs the sliverlight service maker on a Windows Box. Then copy it over.


More Help:
http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958(v=vs.95).aspx